# How to restrict program resources + rights in JVM/OSGi?

Tags: java, security, osgi

I want to create a website where people can solve programming tasks and eventually upload their solution (in any JVM-language) in order to verify it and share it with others.

I figured **OSGi** (learning it right now) might be a good tool to handle this task (is it?). But obviously I'm a little anxious about letting other people executing their code on my host (btw, a input/output-based solution is no alternative).

So I figured I need to find out

**a) how to allow/restrict certain Java functionality** (e.g. starting a thread, sending a mail, writing a file etc.)

and

**b) how to limit a program's/bundle's CPU/RAM resources** so no one could bring the host down with an endless loop for example.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) I think the safest solution would be to create dedicated JVMs for each user-submitted solution. This way, you have all your operating system's tools at hand.

a) Java functionality may be restricted using [Permissions](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/security/permissions.html). I've never tried to do something sophisticated with it, but it certainly isn't trivial to make a solid policy for 3rd party input. Maybe Google's Appengine SDK might help. I suspect that it is using permissions to mimic Appengine's behaviour locally.

Comment: thanks for the answer - gave me a few hints to do further research